# Writing double series in R

Tags: r, loops, syntax, iteration, wolfram-mathematica

I am a newcomer to R and I am facing the following problem. I need to convert an expression from Mathematica to R. In mathematica the syntax is the following:

```
hc=-1.5;
g[x_]:=If[x<0,Ceiling[Abs[x]],Floor[x]];
Sum[f[i,j],{i,0,5},{j,0,i+Sign[hc]*g[hc]}]
```

the output is the following:

```
f[2,0]+f[3,0]+f[3,1]+f[4,0]+f[4,1]+f[4,2]+f[5,0]+f[5,1]+f[5,2]+f[5,3]
```

Now I am trying to do the same in R. Since I am searching how to do so, I use a double for iteration to just print the elements I will sum later.

hence I write

```
hcp = -1.5


ceil_floor = function (x) {
  if(x < 0) { 
    ceiling( abs(x))
    } else {
      floor(x)
    }
}

for (i in 0:5) {
  for (j in 0 : (i + (sign(hcp) * ceil_floor(hcp)))) {
    print( paste0(i,":",j) )
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
[1] "0:0"
[1] "0:-1"
[1] "0:-2"
[1] "1:0"
[1] "1:-1"
[1] "2:0"
[1] "3:0"
[1] "3:1"
[1] "4:0"
[1] "4:1"
[1] "4:2"
[1] "5:0"
[1] "5:1"
[1] "5:2"
[1] "5:3"
```

The problem here lies with : 0-0,1:0, 0:-1,0:-2,1:-1. I don't really have a problem with negative values, since the y will all be equal to zero eventually, but I shouldn't get 0-0,1-0. I guess R handles differently the `for (i in 0:(-2))` than mathematica.

Can someone help?

Comment: how comes that in your mathematica example you don't have `f[0,something]` if `i` span from 0 to 5 ?

Comment: that's how mathematica handles it  (sum's limits). If I wrote it using `for` I would get the same error i thing.

Comment: @denis The bounds of the `j` iterator depend on `i`. When `i==0`, the upper bound of the `j` iterator is negative. Note that the lower bound of `j` is `0`. This means that this iteration is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Mathematica tabulation, like so:

```
Table[f[i, j], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, i + Sign[hc]*g[hc]}]
```

output:

> ```
> {{}, {}, {f[2, 0]}, {f[3, 0], f[3, 1]},
>  {f[4, 0], f[4, 1], f[4, 2]}, {f[5, 0], f[5, 1], f[5, 2], f[5, 3]}}
> ```

you will see that, due to the way Mathematica's iterators work, the following permutations produced by your R code are not present, and are not included in the summation.

```
[1] "0:0"
[1] "0:-1"
[1] "0:-2"
[1] "1:0"
[1] "1:-1"
```

Comment: So how to i reproduce sum’s way in R?

Comment: The iteration produces no result when *jmax* is less than *jmin*, i.e. zero.  Than happens when *i* is 0 or 1, e.g. `1 + Sign[hc]*g[hc] = -1`, so start *imin* at 2 in your transcription.  I.e. `Sum[f[i, j], {i,` **2** `, 5}, {j, 0, i + Sign[hc]*g[hc]}]` -  write that in R.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I believe you should write it as `for (i in (-2):0)` for negative values

Comment: hc can be either positive or negative, and the values of f can change respectively, if hc=1.5 i should get:`f[0,0]+f[0,1]+f[1,0]+f[1,1]+f[1,2]+f[2,0]+f[2,1]+f[2,2]+f[2,3]...`